# Batch file - robocopy archive to new server

Tags: batch-file, delimiter, robocopy

im trying to create a batch file that will duplicate '%%s' in the new location (new server) but only copy over a folder/files under it if that folder exists. Below is my batch, getting an error '%%s unexpected at this time', not sure why as i use this delims code all the time without issue.

```
for /f "delims=|" %%s in ('dir /ad/b') DO (
if exist "\\%%s\Folder\Archive" robocopy "\\%%s\Folder\Archive" "\\server\%%s\Archive" /E /MOVE
)
```

Comment: I do not get your error, but I do get my local folders names being accessed as a server name `\\%%s\...`.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an error there - is there more to the batch file?  The error could be elsewhere - or an extended character has crept into the script.

Comment: all good. i kept getting that error, but i just removed if exist. log file shows errors when a path isn't valid but oh well, it works.

Comment: You reminded me that `if exist folder` doesn't work properly over a LAN.  It was discussed at dostips.com from memory.